# Is there a group in this cyclic sequence of numbers?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Introduction**.  Take a function like $f(x) = (x^2 + 1) \bmod{1763}$.  Define an initial value such as $x_0 = 0$.  Iterate $f$ so that we get the sequence $0, 43, 215, 817, 430, 1376, [1634, 1591, 1032, 387]$ where the brackets denote a cycle in the sequence.  Sequences such as this one must always close a cycle back on themselves.

**Question**.  Can we form a group at all using the elements of such sequences?  What would the operation be?

**Attempted solution**.  My first impression is that we cannot form a group.  The typical identity $1$ for modular arithmetic is not in the cycle.  Perhaps we can take any element in cycle as an identity, but group identities are unique and this approach will make any element in the cycle as an identity.  I can't see how we can take an element in the cycle and somehow make it a unique identity under any operation whatsoever, so I don't think there's any possibility of forming a (cyclic) group with this cycle.  If the group would not be cyclic, that would seem very strange because the very creation of the sequence is through a cyclic process, so I'm not seeing any possibility there.  I'm looking for possibly an approach here that can produce a formal argument.

**Disclaimer**.  This is not homework.  I'm just investigating such sequences and seeing what sort of theories could teach me more about them.

Comment: Title: do you really mean [algebraic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_group)? Or just "group".

Comment: Not sure what you are after.  What might an element of your "group" look like?  What operation on the elements would you be interested in?

Comment: I meant a group.  I didn't know an algebraic group was something else entirely.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I'm after a way to define a group operation on those elements generated by the function $f$.  Since $f$ is iterated, we can sort of draw a circle using the elements in the cycle.  It resembles a cyclic group, but I'm afraid there's no way to find a group there.  The operation I would like to define is an operation involving $f$.  For example, perhaps I could define $f^m \otimes f^n = f^{m + n}$ where $f^i$ means $i$ iterations of $f$ starting from $x_0$, the initial value.  That is, $f^1 = f(x_0), f^2 = f(f(x_0))$.

Comment: You can make any set into a group using the free product. What would be inverses under the scheme you're considering?

Comment: What do you mean by "free product"?  The elements of this sequence can all be written as $f^i$ where this notation means $i$ iterations starting from some fixed element in the cycle.  (I don't know which element to fix, but I can try choosing the first element in the sequence that's not in its tail.  That's $1634$ in the example in the question.)  So the inverse of $f^i$ would be $f^{r - i}$ where $r$ is the length of the cycle.

Comment: For example, $f^2 = 1032$ and $f^{-2} = f^{4 - 2} = f^{2} = 1032$, so the inverse of $f^2$ is itself because starting at $1032$ and iterating $f$ two more times sends us back to $1634$, which is our chosen identity.

Comment: By the way, I've already verified that associativity holds in the operation I implicitly defined with my example above --- which is $f^m \otimes f^n = f^{m + n}$.  So I have associativity, I have inverses.  Do I have an identity?  I chose $1634$ as the identity in the example I gave.  So, unlike when I started the question, I am now inclined to say there is a way to define a group there.  Am I not seeing something important?  Thank you.

Comment: You describe something quite like [Pollard's rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) for factoring, at least the iteration modulo $N$ of polynomial function $f(x) = x^2 + 1$.  But the actual values you put in your Question make no sense, arithmetically speaking.  E.g. $f(0) = 1$, not $43$ as you would have us believe.  Were you just making up nonsense values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a thing as a group acting on a set. For example, the permutation group $S_n$ acts on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. That is what we have here: The operation $f(x)=x^2+1 \pmod {1763}$ acting on the set $T=\{1634,1591,2032,387\}$, permutes the elements of $T$.  Thus $f$ acting on $T$ indeed generates a group $G$ acting on $T$. In particular, here $f$ acting on $T$ generates a group $G$ with precisely $4$ elements i.e.,  $G=\{f, f○f, f○f○f, e\}$.

Comment: I think you illuminated everything here.  So what I'm looking at is an instance of the permutation group $S_n$.  That'd be $S_4$ in my example.  The operation is function composition and the group is some kind of cyclic additive group.  Am I saying the right names here?  Thank you.

Comment: Well, $f$ is an *element* in $S_4$, and so the 4-element group $G$ generated by $f$ is a *subgroup* of $S_4$. And yes $G$ is cyclic and has order $4$ and so is ismorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.